# Vuetify, tooltips: what are "on" and "attrs" for?

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I looked for "Tooltip" in the Vuetify documentation, and I found this example:

```
<v-tooltip left>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      dark
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >Left</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Left tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

What are `on` and `attrs` for? And why are they mandatory?

Also, is this the correct way to listen for the `click` event?

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn v-on="{...on, click: onToggle }" icon>
      <v-icon>mdi-eye</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  Show password
</v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 10):

I could explain myself what that means, but I consider that this video explains it a lot better I let you the time where it stars explaining the utility of v-on and attrs

Just take a look to the section **Transparent wrappers**

https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k?t=1314

**Summary**

**v-on**: Binds a series of listener functions

More in: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

**$attrs**: Stores the attributes setted in the parent component, you can reuse them in a inner component

More in: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

You can find other usages besides of what is shown in the video, but `transparent wrappers` are a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

So far I understand the `v-on` events of the parent (the `v-tooltip` component) are events of the child (the `v-btn` component) by doing `v-on="on"`.

For a conditional 'inheritance' of the `v-on` events, you can do for example

```html
<!-- displayTootip is true/false -->
<v-btn
  v-bind="attrs"
  v-on="displayTootip ? on : null"
>Left</v-btn>
```

For second part of the question, the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#visibility) provide an example to display the toogle programmatically using v-model.